# Crystal report formula for adding/subtracting value from one field to another field

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a report which has two fields: `BOX` and `TRAYS`, which are then summarize in each group using sum formula. And then there is a grand total of these fields are also shown. Now the problem is that I want to convert trays to boxes if their count increase from 12, and add 1 box to box field. If boxes are 2 and trays are 14 then the box field will change to 3 and trays field will change to 2. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create 2 formulas(one per group and another for grand total) and sum `int(your trays summary/12) + your box summary`. That will return your desire result. `int` is going to round down the division between your trays summary and 12. Hope that help you

Comment: You are more than welcome. Glad I could help you! @MehmoodHassan